# Issue with custom recordInterceptor not working after upgrading from Spring Kafka 2.8.x to 3.0.9

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I recently upgraded from Spring Kafka 2.8.x to 3.0.9, and after running tests, I noticed that my custom `recordInterceptor` is no longer functioning as expected. Our `recordInterceptor` is designed to skip messages with certain `typeId` values that are not used by our team.

Upon investigation, I discovered that the condition for setting the `earlyRecordInterceptor` in `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` has changed compared to the previous version.

I couldn't find any information about this change in the release notes for version 3.0.9.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or knows about the changes related to this in Spring Kafka 3.0.9?
2.8.x earlyRecordInterceptor

```
private final RecordInterceptor<K, V> earlyRecordInterceptor =
        isInterceptBeforeTx() || this.transactionManager == null
                ? getRecordInterceptor()
                : null;
```

3.0.9

```
private final RecordInterceptor<K, V> earlyRecordInterceptor =
        isInterceptBeforeTx() && this.transactionManager != null
                ? getRecordInterceptor()
                : null;
```

Below is my interceptor code:

```
class NotSupportedMessageFilter<K, V> : RecordInterceptor<K, V> {

    private val consumerTokens = setOf<String>("sample")
 
    override fun intercept(record: ConsumerRecord<K, V>, consumer: Consumer<K, V>): ConsumerRecord<K, V>? {
        if (isNotSupportedMessage(record)) {
            consumer.commitAsync()
            return null
        }
        return record
    }

    private fun isNotSupportedMessage(record: ConsumerRecord<K, V>): Boolean {
        val headerIterator: Iterator<Header> = record.headers()
            .headers(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.DEFAULT_CLASSID_FIELD_NAME).iterator()
        if (!headerIterator.hasNext()) {
            return false
        }
        val token = String(headerIterator.next().value(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        return !consumerTokens.contains(token)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/2727
it seems that the changes were made to ensure that the errorHandler is invoked.

Does this mean that the functionality previously handled by my custom interceptor should now be implemented within the errorHandler?

Comment: Apparently you need a transaction manager now, previously you didn't. Have you configured a tx manager? Also couldn't you just use the regular `recordInterceptor` instead of the `earlyRecordInterceptor`?

Comment: thank you your answer.

1.We are not configuring a transaction manager. This is because we don't need a transaction manager. While we could add one, doing so might introduce unpredictable side effects.  
  
2. We want to execute the recordInterceptor, but we can't because it checks for VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER before processing the message. The reason it catches this exception is because we received a type id that we don't use.

Comment: You probably need to use `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` with a `setFailedDeserializationFunction()`. If that function is not provided the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` returns `null`. There is also `ConsumerProperties.checkDeserExWhenValueNull` property for your consideration. But that still would throw an exception before your interceptor.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Artem Bilan
. You are correct. I am indeed using ErrorHandlingDeserializer. It indeed sets null for the value. However, I mentioned that it checks VALUE_DESERIALIZER_EXCEPTION_HEADER before checkDeserExWhenValueNull.

As you rightly pointed out, even with ErrorHandlingDeserializer, you cannot trigger the execution of RecordInterceptor.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` with a `setFailedDeserializationFunction()`. If that function is not provided the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` returns `null`.

There is also `ConsumerProperties.checkDeserExWhenValueNull` property for your consideration. But that still would throw an exception before your interceptor.